# Updating one React's components state from another

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, webpack, state

I am trying to  change the state of one of my components through another component. Note that I am new to reactJs 

In my **parents component** I have a state named: **_SPCommandBarDisabled**

```
this.state = {
  _SPCommandBarDisabled: true
}
```

In a **child** component (the **SPSearchBox**) the event is triggered that changes the state of **_SPCommandBarDisabled** (the log shows that the state is actually changed)

```
public onSearchTextChanged(newText: any) {
this.setState({ _SPCommandBarDisabled: false },
  () => { console.log("New _SPCommandBarDisabled: " + this.state._SPCommandBarDisabled) }
);
```

However, in my 2nd child (the **SPCommandBar** component) the value is not updated.
This is the code from my **parents component**

```
export default class StudentDocumentsHelper extends React.Component<IStudentDocumentsHelperProps, any> {
  constructor() {
    super();

    this.state = {
      _SPCommandBarDisabled: true
    }
    this.onSearchTextChanged = this.onSearchTextChanged.bind(this);
  }

  public render(): React.ReactElement<IStudentDocumentsHelperProps> {
    return (
      <div>
        <SPCommandBar isDisabled={this.state._SPCommandBarDisabled} />
        <SPSearchBox onTextChange={this.onSearchTextChanged} />
        <SPListView />
      </div>
    );
  }

  public onSearchTextChanged(newText: any) {
    this.setState({ _SPCommandBarDisabled: false },
      () => { console.log("New _SPCommandBarDisabled: " + this.state._SPCommandBarDisabled) }
    );
  }
}
```

And the **SPCommandBar** inherits from props

```
export interface ISPCommandBar {
    isDisabled: boolean;
}

export class SPCommandBar extends React.Component<ISPCommandBar, any> {
    constructor(props: any) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            _SPCommandBarDisabled: this.props.isDisabled
        };
    }
```

> **Update**

In my **SPCommandBar** component I was inheriting the **_SPCommandBarDisabled** prop and parsing it to the state.

In my **SPCommandBar**'s render() method I was setting the **enabled** value by referring to the state:

```
disabled: this.state._SPCommandBarDisabled
```

And when updating the parents state, the child state did not seem to get updated. However, when referring to the props instead of the state it is working:

```
disabled: this.props.isDisabled
```

I wonder if I just solved my own problem or is this **not** the way it should be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT after original poster found the solution:

The constructor function is only called once, when the component is created, when the props you pass to the component change, the constructor won't be called again, but rather componentWillReceiveProps, you can read more [here](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html)

Original Answer:

I think the error is you are using this.props, instead of just props (which are passed on the definition of the constructor function)

Try to change this:

```
this.state = {
    _SPCommandBarDisabled: props.isDisabled
};
```

Comment: No, unfortunately the **_SPCommandBarDisabled** does not change in the SPCommandBar component

Comment: Ah, just read your update, indeed, you are doing it incorrectly, your components constructor function is only called once, when it is created, if the props change then the state won't be updated, what you are looking for is either directly using the prop (and react takes care of the rest) or binding it both in the constructor and on componentWillReceiveProps.